# Spring integration : how to handle transaction commit while specific exception occurs

Tags: transactions, spring-integration

Our application, based on spring integration (Spring Boot v2.2.5.RELEASE, Spring v5.2.4.RELEASE), accepts JMS messages via *inboundGateway* component, process a message flow and finally produces a JMS message as result in a different queue.

In order to make our flow  **transactional**, we configure the following :

- At the *inboundGateway* component, we attach a **JmsTransactionManager** to the *DefaultMessageListenerContainer* instance
- The **input flow**

```
IntegrationFlows.from(Jms.inboundGateway(defaultMessageListenerContainer).errorChannel(ERROR_CHANNEL));
```

- At the **process flow**

```
...
 .transform(jsonTransformer(), e -> e.transactional(true))
.handle (..)
```

**NB :** the input flow and the process flow are connected through an **executor channel**

This works fine except for a particular scenario : when the process flow throws **a specific unchecked exception**, then we expect that it will be propagated to the ErrorHandler, where it **will be written to an error queue AND transaction have to be COMMITTED**. BUT the actual is that the transaction is rollbacked and the message is requeued.

My questions are :

- is our transaction configuration well defined?  in addition of setting up the TX manager, is it mandatory to configure the *MessageListenerContainer* property **SessionTransacted to true**?
- How to make commit even when the process flow throws the specific exception?  how and where to explicitly set/force the JMS transaction to be commited?

Thanks in advance,

Comment: Why do you need to make it transactional at all since your goal is to always ackk the message?

Comment: Why do you use gateway for inbound messages? Just to have a blocking state to not lose a transaction? Doesn't look like you expect a reply from your downstream flow? Would you mind to clarify, please?

Comment: the inboundGateway is an endpoint already defined in the existing integration flow and not a choice for transactional aspect. Our purpose is to make the entire message flow transactional :

Comment: my comment was truncated.. the _inboundGateway_ is an endpoint already defined in the existing integration flow and not a choice for transactional aspect. Also, we don't expect a reply from the downstream flow.  Our purpose is to make the entire message flow transactional : we need transaction to be commited if **(1)** message flow completed and **(2) ONLY when a SPECIFIC exception/case occurs**. **(3)** Otherwise, TX is rollebacked. So, actually, we don't succeed to handle the second case (2) as described above.

Comment: The transaction context is definitely tied with a thread it is initiated in. So, as long as we start shifting work to other threads we exit from transactional boundaries. Even if that thread is still blocked waiting for reply in the async barrier (and keeps transaction active, of course), it doesn't mean that the work in that other thread is a part of the mentioned transaction. Does it make sense?

Comment: yes i understood but in our case, both message read from JMS and message processing are executed by the same thread as we use the same threadPool for the **messageListener** and the downstream flow.

Comment: Since you don't expect a reply from downstream the inbound gateway is a wrong choice. This way, without replies, you end up we resource leaking and unexpected errors when no replies arrive in time. The async hand off in the middle of the flow is also wrong decision since it is not a part of activated before transaction.

Comment: No, that's not how thread pool works. The `ExecutorChannel` delegates the task to a thread pool and it is performed on one which is free at the moment or it is stack in the work queue until some thread is free. You can't claim the same thread from async hand off. More over you block it in the Inbound Gateway waiting for reply.

Comment: See `RuleBasedTransactionAttribute` to be set on the `AbstractPollingMessageListenerContainer` for conditional roll back of the original JMS transaction. Although I still think that design for the logic is wrong. Not sure what is your business purpose, but there are a lot of flaws we see right now in the solution. Hard to find a fix if components are abused...

Comment: thanks @ArtemBilan for your advices. i will consider replace the gateway by a messageDrivenAdapter. But still a questions : setting up the TX manager and property SessionTransacted to true, are they exclusive? Also, have you an example of impl using RuleBasedTransactionAttribute?